# Can I ask the compiler to forbid defining a generic version of a member function of a templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Suppose I have an interface `I`, and a templated class `C` which implements the interface:

```
class I {
public:
  virtual int foo() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class C : public I {
public:
  int foo() override;
};
```

I want there to be only two instantiations of `C`, with types `T1` and `T2`. I want to specialize `foo()` for each of them. I can do this in my `.cpp` file like this:

```
template<>
C<T1>::foo() { return 1; }

template<>
C<T2>::foo() { return 2; }

template class C<T1>;
template class C<T2>;
```

I am wary that someone will come along with more template parameters they want to use for `C`, such as `T3` and `T4`, and will define a generic `foo()`

```
template<typename T>
C::foo() { return 0; }

// (with appropriate specialization declarations)
template class C<T3>;
template class C<T4>;
```

because then, in a final scenario, someone could add a fifth type and forget to specialize `foo()` for it:

```
// forgotten:
// template<>
// C::<T5>::foo() { return 5; }

template class C<T5>;
```

How can I ask the compiler to complain about someone adding the generic `foo()`, either in a unit test or in the implementation of `C`?

Comment: Somebody could make a template<typename T> class D : public I { ... }; which will also be an I ,avoiding the restrictions;

Comment: That's a good point. I'm not as concerned about that at the moment: hopefully if someone is adding a new implementation of `I` they know what they are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the generic definition yourself:

```
template<typename T>
int C<T>::foo() { static_assert(!std::is_same_v<T,T>, "Missing specialization of C<T>::foo()!"); return 0; }
```

Since the condition for the `static_assert` is always false, everyone trying to use `C` with a not yet specialized type will get the static assertion error (which will additionally provide a useful hint as to how to solve this problem).

Because you already provided a definition for `C<T>::foo()` anyone trying to provide his own generic definition of `C<T>::foo()` will get a compiler error because of redefinition.

Note that the condition inside the `static_assert` must be dependent on the template type to only trigger the assertion upon template instantiation.

Comment: Sorry but... no valid specialization can be generated form your generic definition so... isn't ill formed your code?

Comment: @max66 I'm not sure what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: @AlexanderBrown - I mean that, if I'm not wrong (but I'm not a language layer), the code in this answer is "ill formed" because no valid specialization can be generated. In short: is wrong.

Comment: I think that's the point. I want to enforce that generating specializations should result in a compile-time error. I only want explicit specializations to be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept only two template types for `T`... what about a `static_assert()`

```
template<typename T>
class C : public I {

   static_assert(    std::is_same<T, T1>::value
                  or std::is_same<T, T2>::value, "bad parameter");

public:
  int foo() override;
};
```

Comment: This will work, and is useful, thank you. I actually have six initial types (T1, ..., T6), so I was hoping to not have to write them all out. If that's the best way to do it though I'm OK with it

Comment: @AlexanderBrown How would you want to restrict template arguments to some types only without writing them out somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I meant write them all out *again*. I have them all declared `template class C<T1>; ...` already, but I didn't want to have to write the list twice.